# Homebrew opens everytime I open the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I recently installed homebrew on my M1 Mac and it works perfectly but everytime I open the terminal it instantly executes the brew command.

I hope someone can help me, thank you! This is what I see everytime I open a new terminal:

```
Last login: Sat Mar 11 19:01:26 on ttys002
Example usage:
  brew search TEXT|/REGEX/
  brew info [FORMULA|CASK...]
  brew install FORMULA|CASK...
  brew update
  brew upgrade [FORMULA|CASK...]
  brew uninstall FORMULA|CASK...
  brew list [FORMULA|CASK...]

Troubleshooting:
  brew config
  brew doctor
  brew install --verbose --debug FORMULA|CASK

Contributing:
  brew create URL [--no-fetch]
  brew edit [FORMULA|CASK...]

Further help:
  brew commands
  brew help [COMMAND]
  man brew
  https://docs.brew.sh
fedegutman@Federicos-MBP ~ %
```

Comment: In your home folder, look in `.zshrc` and `.zshenv` for commands that might be running `brew`

Comment: @Ezekiel thank you for the reply! im new to this so could you explain a bit further how to do that? There does not seem to be anything called `.zshrc` or `.zshenv` in my home folder.

Comment: It’s unlikely to be in `.zshenv`.  In terminal, type `cat ~/.zshrc | pbcopy` and paste the contents to  your question with an [edit].  Do the same for `.zprofile`.  To see the hidden files in your home directory, type `ls -lah ~/`

Comment: Where does the homebrew installer tell you to put the line that changes the path?  That has a `brew` invocation in it to output the path.  If the OP didn't add it correctly, that would lead to an error.

Comment: You can just type `open ~/.zshrc` and it will open in Text Edit

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error mentioned in the question, and I managed to solve it by removing the line of code that was in the `.zprofile` file.

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew)"
```